# Não consigo aumentar o contador no Tkinter!

Tags: python, tkinter

Ultimamente tenho dedicado o meu tempo a um programa executável para computador baseado em Tkinter, no qual você dá uma volta em uma pista e a cada vez que completa uma volta, clica em um botão. Daí ele mostra a quantidade de voltas que você já deu. Para acumular a quantidade de voltas, estava usando um contador como:

contador = 0
contador += 1

o problema é que o contador para no 1.
Vou deixar o código inteiro aqui pra quem quiser entender melhor.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Contador de voltas')

contador = 0

voltas = Label(root, text=f'Número de voltas: {contador}')
voltas.pack()

def comando():
    voltas['text']=f'Número de voltas: {contador}'

botao = Button(root, text='Volta', padx=10, pady=10, command=comando)
botao.pack()

if botao:
    contador += 1

root.mainloop()
```

é bem simples em si, mas não estou conseguindo terminar o projeto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*contador* sempre será 1, pois ele é executado uma única vez, depois que entra na função `root.mainloop()`, Tkinter fica preso na função designada pelos eventos e atualizações da janela.

Se você quer que ao clicar no botão "volta", ele alimente o contador, faça isso dentro da função `comando()`.

Exemplo:

```
def comando():
    global contador
    contador += 1
    voltas['text'] = f'Número de voltas: {contador}'
```

Se você precisa que seja efetuada uma rotina junto com Tkinter, periodicamente, experimente a função `after()`.

```
after(parent, ms, function = None, *args)
```

Então, se você quer que o contador seja alimentado a cada 1 segundo, defina:

```
after(1000, alimenta_contador)
```

Defina então a função `alimenta_contador()`, algo como isso:

```
def alimenta_contador():
    contador += 1
    after(1000, alimenta_contador)
```

Note que dentro de `alimenta_contador()`, estamos chamando `after()` novamente, criando assim uma tarefa a ser executada no futuro.

Comment: Então, pelo que vi a função after só funciona com tempo. Eu gostaria de uma função que adicionasse uma volta a cada vez que o botão fosse pressionado, e não com uma regularidade de tempo. Teria alguma opção do tipo? Muito obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: @GabrielMonteiro isso está incluído na resposta: Se você quer que ao clicar no botão "volta", ele alimente o contador, faça isso dentro da função comando(). Então, antes de exibir o número de voltas, adicione ao contador.

Comment: Então, eu até ia editar o comentário acima, mas outra coisa que eu percebi é que dentro da função não é possível colocar por exemplo contador += 1, que dá erro.

Comment: @GabrielMonteiro defina contador como escopo global, pois dessa forma você garante que o contador não seja recriada a cada chamada da função, editei a resposta para incluir uma solução.

Comment: Agora sim! Muito obrigado, de coração!!! Tive que dar uma pequena reformulada no código mas deu certo. Como posso retribuir sua ajuda?

Comment: @GabrielMonteiro Você já o fez! Sempre que uma resposta agradar, solucionar seu problema, você como autor do tópico tem direito de marcar uma melhor resposta, além disso, nas respostas competentes que foram úteis, tem o botão de seta para cima, que indica que a resposta foi útil (agregou), e também seta para baixo - que indica que a resposta foi inútil (não agregou). No mais, sucesso.

Answer (score -3):

Solução:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Contador de voltas')
root.geometry("300x75")

contador = 0

voltas = Label(root, text=f'Número de voltas: {contador}')
voltas.pack()

def comando():
    global contador
    contador += 1
    voltas['text']=f'Número de voltas: {contador}'


botao = Button(root, text='Volta', padx=10, pady=10, command=comando)
botao.pack()


root.mainloop()
```